# only last iteration value is being updated in a dictionary in robot framework

Tags: python, dictionary, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

```
gtx
    [Arguments]    @{crdnvlslst_params_args}
    ${dictx}    Create Dictionary
    ${dictx_card_vals}    Create Dictionary
    ${lenofcard}=    Get Length    ${crdnvlslst_params_args}
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{crdnvlslst_params_args}
        ${card}    ${cardtext}=    Evaluate    "${element}".split("=")
        FOR    ${x}    IN RANGE    1    ${lenofcard}+${1}
            ${card_vals}    Set Variable    ${x}
            Set To Dictionary    ${dictx_card_vals}    card_head=${card_vals}    card_val=${EMPTY}
        END
        Set To Dictionary    ${dictx}    ${card}    ${dictx_card_vals}
        Log To Console    ${dictx}
    END
```

It is giving output :

```
{'C1': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C2': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C5': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C6': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}}
```

But the expected output should be :

```
{'C1': {'card_head': 1, 'card_val': ''}, 'C2': {'card_head': 2, 'card_val': ''}, 'C5': {'card_head': 3, 'card_val': ''}, 'C6': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}}
```

I am new to robot framework please help.

I tried various ways.
like using temporary dictionary to store and then update.it didn't work. Please help

Answer (score 0):

In the provided code snippet, for each iteration of the outer for loop, the inner loop runs four times. Consequently, it results in the same value being assigned to the ${dictx_card_vals} dictionary variable. Try changing the code as below to address this and achieve the expected output, consider modifying your code as follows:

```
gtx
    [Arguments]    @{crdnvlslst_params_args}
    ${dictx}    Create Dictionary
    ${dictx_card_vals}    Create Dictionary
    ${lenofcard}=    Get Length    ${crdnvlslst_params_args}
    ${x}=   Set Variable    ${0}
    FOR    ${element}    IN    @{crdnvlslst_params_args}
        ${card}    ${cardtext}=    Evaluate    "${element}".split("=")
        ${x}   evaluate   ${x}+${1}
        Set To Dictionary    ${dictx_card_vals}    card_head=${x}    card_val=${EMPTY}
        Set To Dictionary    ${dictx}    ${card}    ${dictx_card_vals}
    END
```

Comment: Still getting the same output.

{'C1': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C2': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C5': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}, 'C6': {'card_head': 4, 'card_val': ''}}